# SelectedItem in ListView disappears

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have created a minimalistic sample using a ListView with three items in it and a contentControl next to it that displays the selected ListViewItem. What puzzles me is that when I select an Item it is shown correctly on the ContentControl but gets so small in the ListView like if it was disappearing. Can anyone explain me what happens here?

The MainWindow with the ListView and the ContentControl in a grid. The ContentControl.Content binds to the selected item of the ListView.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListViewItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedListViewItem}"/>
        <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding SelectedListViewItem}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The MainWindow has the DataContext set to the MainWindowViewModel

```
using System.Windows;
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
}
```

The MainWindowViewModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged and holds the ListViewItems as well as the SelectedListViewItem.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Controls;

public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        ListViewItems = new ObservableCollection<Control>()
        {
            new TextBox(){ Text = "TB1", IsReadOnly = true },
            new TextBox(){ Text = "TB2", IsReadOnly = true },
            new TextBox(){ Text = "TB3", IsReadOnly = true },
        };
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Control> _listViewItems;
    private Control _selectedListViewItem;

    public ObservableCollection<Control> ListViewItems
    {
        get
        {
            return _listViewItems;
        }
        set
        {
            if (SetProperty(ref _listViewItems, value))
            {
            }
        }
    }

    public Control SelectedListViewItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedListViewItem;
        }
        set
        {
            if (SetProperty(ref _selectedListViewItem, value))
            {
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected virtual bool SetProperty<T>(ref T backingField, T newValue, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var ret = false;
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingField, newValue))
        {
            backingField = newValue;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            ret = true;
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

I know that the ViewModel should not hold any reference to any view. From the minimal sample, however, this was required. The question for me is why the ListViewItems "disappear".

[image: Effect of a buttonclick]

I clicked on the first ListViewItem, TB1. It gets displayed on the contentcontrol on the right but the ListView now looks strange. I can repeat that for the other ListViewItems as well.

[image]

This is after clicking also on TB2 and then finally on TB3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is a control can only appear once in the ui.

You're building controls in code.

When you select one it's taken from where you selected it and moved to where you bound it to.

Don't build controls in code.

Use mvvm.

Build data ( viewmodels ) and bind to ui.

Datatemplate that data into controls.

Comment: Thank you, that very well explains what I observed. I wasn't aware of that moving behaviour.